# octo.exe command failure is not failing bamboo build task

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo, continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

I'm running octo.exe command to push nuget packages to octopus and to create a release in octopus. Now for any reason if octo.exe command fails, it's not failing the bamboo build task, it continues to execute other steps in the build plan. Is there any way to tell bamboo that octo command is failing?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using octopustools prior to 3.3.3 it could be a bug

http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/problems/43769-octoexe-returns-exit-code-0-regardless-of-failure